# Django Filter name "todo__test" is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to filter my Todos by the test_id pulled from the URL. It pulls the id from the URL but it cant seem to filter with todo__test. I have also tried "test", "Todo.test.test_id", "Todo.test". I guess I'm confused about what variable I need to filter and the Django restframework documentation doesn't explicitly show what variable to use. Their example uses "purchaser__username" which I don't understand where it comes from. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

```
class TodoList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        test_id = self.kwargs['test_id']
        return Todo.objects.filter(todo__test == test_id)

class Todo(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content + ' - ' + self.test.test_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['test_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it will be like this. you passed incorrect foreign key field name.
`Todo.objects.filter(test_id='whatever_value')`